# How to select from a single table with a condition across multiple rows of the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that includes columns for medical numbers and procedures. There are a lot of rows and medical numbers can be repeated with many procedures; for example:

```
Mid_no    procedure
--------------------
100.          20
100.          30
200.          30
```

I want to select all `mid_no` that have procedure 30 and do not have procedure 20. In the above example, the desired result would be:

```
Mid_no.    Procedure
---------------------
200.        30
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.mid_no,
  t.procedure
FROM TABLE t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE t1 WHERE t1.mid_no = t.mid_no AND t1.procedure = 20
  )
AND t.procedure = 30;
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand T is my table what is T1?

Comment: @ahmeddevil it's an alias of the table. It's useful so that we don't have to write the full table name to qualify columns.

Comment: @ahmed use your own table name in place of **TABLE** in the above query

Answer (score 1):

```
select mid_no from table where procedure = 30
intersect
select mid_no from table where procedure != 20
```

Answer (score 0):

With a single scan of your table, you can use:

```
select distinct Mid_no
from (
        select count(case when procedure=20 then 1 end ) over ( partition by Mid_no) as has20,
               count(case when procedure=30 then 1 end ) over ( partition by Mid_no) as has30,
               Mid_no
        from yourTable
     )
where has20 = 0 
  and has30 != 0
```

The internal query counts the number of occurrences of `20` and `30` in two different  values, for each `Mid_no`; the external one simply picks the only records with no occurrence of `20` and at least one occurrenxe of `30`.